# Determine the convergence of series $ \sum\frac{2^n+3^n}{4^n-5^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove whether the following series converge or diverge.

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n+3^n}{4^n-5^n}$$

I think this series converge so I tried to prove with ratio test and comparison test but it did not work.

Please give me ideas or hints on how to solve this question, thanks to anybody who helps.

Comment: Root Test works fine, if we have to give justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{2^n+3^n}{4^n-5^n}\right|=\left(\frac35\right)^n\frac{\left(\frac23\right)^n+1}{\left|\left(\frac45\right)^n-1\right|}\le5\left(\frac35\right)^n\left[\left(\frac23\right)^n+1\right]\le10\left(\frac35\right)^n$$

Further hint: since $\;0<\left(\frac45\right)^n<\frac45\;$ , we have that

$$-1<\left(\frac45\right)^n-1<\frac45-1=-\frac15$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{2^n+3^n}{4^n-5^n} = \dfrac{\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n + \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n}{\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n-1} \sim -\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n - \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n$$

when $n\to +\infty$

Comment: How "when $\;n\to\infty\;$",  yet you got an expression that depends on $\;n\;$ ?

Comment: @Timbuc $f(n)\sim g(n)$ when $n\to +\infty$ means $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1$

Comment: @Timbuc The denominator approaches -1. The numerator was left alone.

Comment: That I know, @Petite...yet your rightmost expression *still* has $\;n\;$ in it..!

Comment: @Timbuc In my previous comment, $g(n)$ has $n$ in it, so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem, imo, is that when you write $\;\sim\;$ after your first equality sign, you're passing to the limit $\;n\to\infty\;$ , as you said above...yet you left the two exponents with $\;n\;$ of the fractions $\;\frac23\,,\,\,\frac35\;$ . So you passed to the limit, or you didn't? And if you didn't, then how that $\;\sim\;$ is justified?

Comment: @Timbuc do you agree that $\dfrac{\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n + \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n}{\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n-1} / (-\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n - \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n$$
) \to 1$?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now what you meant , @Petite: I was confusing with the notation O .Thanks.

Comment: @Timbuc You are welcome :)

Comment: I need to upvote this. +1

Answer (score 1):

HINT: 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac{2^n+3^n}{5^n-4^n}}{\dfrac{3^n}{5^n}}=1.
$$

Comment: Sorry but can you explain a bit more, I didn't quite get it.

Comment: @Lucy Is the short extension of my answer enough for you?

Comment: This actually made me slightly more confused because the ratio test I was taught in lectures seem different to what you have shown to me.

Comment: @KolaB. I think you meant the limit comparison test. That's not the ratio test.

Comment: @Lucy Isn't it in the form: If, for nonnegative $a_n$, $b_n$,  $\lim_n (a_n/b_n)=k$, where $0<k<\infty$, then both $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ converge (or diverge)?

Comment: No @KolaB.  That is, as commented, the limit comparison test.

Comment: @Timbuc OK. I've removed improper name.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Do a limit comparison with $\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac35\right)^n$. It may be helpful to note that

$$\frac{2^n+3^n}{3^n}=\left(\frac23\right)^2+1\;,$$

and $$\large\frac{5^n}{4^n-5^n}=\frac1{\frac{4^n-5^n}{5^n}}\;.$$

The motivation here is that $2^n+3^n\approx 3^n$ and $4^n-5^n\approx -5^n$ for very large $n$.