# How to show series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {3^n+4^n}{3^n+5^n}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I've tried let $\frac{3^n+4^n}{3^n+5^n}$ be smaller than $\frac{2*4^n}{2*3^n}$, which is diverge when n tends to infinity.

And the ratio test can't be used in this situation.

Comment: How about $\frac {2 (4^{n})}{5^{n}}$?

Comment: You can give a much better bound. Try disregarding $3^n$ in the denominator

Comment: @getta290krm, got it. I've been stuck there for a long time 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine the convergence of series $ \sum\frac{2^n+3^n}{4^n-5^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044209/determine-the-convergence-of-series-sum-frac2n3n4n-5n)

Comment: You can use the limit comparison test for this, where you make the comparison with $\sum \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the asymptotic behaviour of the function, you get:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{3^n+4^n}{3^n+5^n}\sim \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{4^n}{5^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^n=\frac{1}{1-4/5}-1=4 $$
Hence the series is convergent.